# compatibility matrix

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

How can I model a compatibility matrix database in sql server 2008;
i.e. I have 4 groups of design. If I select group 1 and group 4, my choices will influence group 2 and 3 and will make them unselectable because they are not compatible with my choices.

I'm a beginner, so my explanation might seems watery, pls forgive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of "matrix" is essentially an M:N relationship, only in this case both "axis" of the matrix represent the same thing ("groups of design"). The M:N relationship of a table with itself can be modeled like this:

[image]

Assuming relationships are bidirectional, you should also add: `CHECK(GROUP_ID1 < GROUP_ID2)` in the COMPATIBILITY table. This would, for example, allow (1, 4), but prevent (4, 1) from being in the table.

The example from your question would be represented by the following data in the database:

**GROUP:**

```
GROUP_ID
--------
1
2
3
4
```

**COMPATIBILITY:**

```
GROUP_ID1    GROUP_ID2
---------    ---------
1            4
```

When user selects a group X, you'd run the following query to find which groups it is compatible with. The remaining groups are **in**-compatible.

```
SELECT GROUP_ID1
FROM COMPATIBILITY
WHERE GROUP_ID2 = :X
UNION ALL
SELECT GROUP_ID2
FROM COMPATIBILITY
WHERE GROUP_ID1 = :X
```

For 1, this would return 4 and for 4 it would return 1. In either of these cases, 2 and 3 would not be returned - a sign they are incompatible.

---

On the other hand, if you want do disable 2 and 3 when 1 **and** 4 are selected, but not when just 1 or just 4 is selected, this is a different problem that would be more complicated to model in the relational paradigm. Let me know if that's what you actually need...

Comment: I want 2 and 3 disabled when either 1 OR 4 is selected. SO I guess that pretty much solve it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I implemented this and it works pretty well. But do you know how I can bind this to a WPF combo box, such that the groups are combo box items, and when I select 1 or 4, 2 and 3 becomes disabled or disappears from the combo box items.

Comment: @DevEx Well, if you have bound your combo-box to an `ObservableCollection`, it should automatically change its contents based on changes in the collection.

Comment: could you please show me example online of how I can bind such WPF controls to an ObservableCollection, an easy one for a beginner like me to understand. Thanks

Comment: @DevEx In short: create a property in your Window class that exposes the `ObservableCollection`, then bind it through XAML as you would any collection. You can then programmatically change this collection, based on what you get from the database. I wouldn't be surprised if there are more elegant solutions using Entity Framework, but my work is mostly DBMS-agnostic so I'm not familiar with EF.